# C# How do i get the Right(String) based on one character?

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
MyString = @"C:\\Somepath\otherpath\etc\string";
```

And i need this string (which can be longer than a group of characters)

How can i do something like:

```
NewString = MyString.Right(string, when last "\" is found) ?
```

Comment: Substring and lastindexof will help..

Comment: Some of the [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.8) methods might be more useful than chopping up bits of string

Comment: Is this the name of a file complete with its path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return everything after the last instance of the character '\'.

```
var result = MyString.Substring(MyString.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

Comment: My only suggestion would be to use `MyString?.Substring...`, to handle the case where `MyString` might be `null`.

Answer (score 3):

For a path specifically, you can use [`Path.GetFileName(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Path_GetFileName_System_String_).

```cs
var MyString = @"C:\Somepath\otherpath\etc\string";
var NewString = Path.GetFileName(MyString);
```

Despite the name of the method, it also works on directory names, provided they aren't followed by a trailing backslash. So `C:\directory` becomes `directory`, but `C:\directory\` becomes the empty string. (This might be what you want, based on how you phrased the question.)

Comment: It's nice because it could not care less whether it's a directory, or an extensionless file. It's just "fancy" string manipulation [behind the scenes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,95facc58d06cadd0).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your environment, you might be able to use the new indices and range features that came with C# 8.0

```
var result = MyString.Split('\\')[^1];
```

[Indices and Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a bit of LINQ:

```
var result = MyString?.Split('\\').LastOrDefault();
```